Shrink container if text is wrapped
I have some text in a div. If the text is to long to fit the container, the text should wrap. At the moment the width of the container stays the same, resulting in a margin being added.
Here is a simple example:


.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<div style="width: 200px; display: flex; background:grey; padding: 10px;">
  
  <div class="border"> Child 1 </div>
  <div class="border"> Child 2 </div>

</div>

<div style="width: 200px; display: flex; background:grey; padding: 10px;">
  
  <div class="border"> Child 1 that has a longer text </div>
  <div class="border"> Child 2 </div>

</div>




